# How to compile GNU Emacs 25.1 on 16.10

Tags: compiling, emacs, segmentation-fault, 16.10

I've managed to build and install (using checkinstall) an GNU Emacs 25.1 Debian package on 16.04, but on 16.10 for some unknown reason the compilation fails (at the `make` stage) giving the truncated output:

```
Loading language/czech...
Loading language/slovak...
Loading language/romanian...
Loading language/greek...
Loading language/hebrew...
Loading international/cp51932...
Loading international/eucjp-ms...
Loading language/japanese...
Loading language/korean...
Loading language/lao...
Loading language/tai-viet...
Loading language/thai...
Loading language/tibetan...
Loading language/vietnamese...
Loading language/misc-lang...
Loading language/utf-8-lang...
Loading language/georgian...
Loading language/khmer...
Loading language/burmese...
Loading language/cham...
Loading indent...
Loading emacs-lisp/cl-generic...
Loading frame...
Loading startup...
Loading term/tty-colors...
Loading font-core...
Loading facemenu...
Loading emacs-lisp/syntax...
Loading font-lock...
Loading jit-lock...
Loading mouse...
Loading scroll-bar...
Loading select...
Loading emacs-lisp/timer...
Loading isearch...
Loading rfn-eshadow...
Loading menu-bar...
Loading emacs-lisp/lisp...
Loading textmodes/page...
Loading register...
Loading textmodes/paragraphs...
Loading progmodes/prog-mode...
Loading emacs-lisp/lisp-mode...
Loading progmodes/elisp-mode...
Loading textmodes/text-mode...
Loading textmodes/fill...
Loading newcomment...
Loading replace...
Loading emacs-lisp/tabulated-list...
Loading buff-menu...
Loading fringe...
Loading emacs-lisp/regexp-opt...
Loading image...
Loading international/fontset...
Loading dnd...
Loading tool-bar...
Loading dynamic-setting...
Loading x-dnd...
Loading term/common-win...
Loading term/x-win...
Loading mwheel...
Loading emacs-lisp/float-sup...
Loading vc/vc-hooks...
Loading vc/ediff-hook...
Loading uniquify...
Loading electric...
Loading emacs-lisp/eldoc...
Loading cus-start...
Loading tooltip...
Loading /home/fusion809/Programs/emacs-25.1/lisp/leim/leim-list.el (source)...
Finding pointers to doc strings...
Finding pointers to doc strings...done
Dumping under the name emacs
Makefile:736: recipe for target 'bootstrap-emacs' failed
make[1]: *** [bootstrap-emacs] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fusion809/Programs/emacs-25.1/src'
Makefile:398: recipe for target 'src' failed
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

To be clear I ran:

```
./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-x-toolkit=gtk2 && make
```

and it was at the `make` stage that the build failed. I did run `sudo apt-get build-dep -y emacs24` before running these commands.

EDIT: I can confirm that this segmentation fault occurs even when the `--with-x-toolkit=gtk2` option is substituted with `--with-x-toolkit=gtk3`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is reported as http://debbugs.gnu.org/24682. A workaround is to use `./configure CFLAGS=-no-pie` .